How to deserialize all the extension data for mint account?
If I have the address of a mint account, how can I programmatically check/deserialize (using JS and Rust) all the extension data to see all the extensions enabled for the mint?
Is there a helper function that does this automatically, without having to know beforehand which extensions are enabled?

You have three different options:

requesting the account with jsonParsed encoding should parse all of the extension data for you
in Rust:

use spl_token_2022::{
    extension::{BaseStateWithExtensions, StateWithExtensions},
    state::Mint,
};
... assuming you have the mint data from fetching the account ...
let mint = StateWithExtensions::<PodMint>::unpack(&mint_data).unwrap();
let extension_types = mint.get_extension_types().unwrap();


In JS:

import { getMint, getExtensionTypes, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';

...
const mint = await getMint(connection, address, 'confirmed', TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);
const extensionTypes = getExtensionTypes(mint.tlvData);

