How to check for token extensions in web3.js v1.95?
I'm trying to check if a mint account at a given address has the interest-bearing token extension. In Anchor, we can do this with:
use anchor_spl::{
    token_2022_extensions,
    token_2022::{
        self,
        spl_token_2022::{
            state::Mint,
            extension::{
                interest_bearing_mint::InterestBearingConfig,
                StateWithExtensions, BaseStateWithExtensions
            },
        },
    },

Where I can assert with something like:
        let mint_account_info = ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info();
        let mint_data = mint_account_info.data.borrow();
        let mint = StateWithExtensions::<Mint>::unpack(&mint_data)?;
        
        let ui_amount = mint.get_extension::<InterestBearingConfig>()
            .map_err(|_| ProgramError::NoInterestBeardingExtensionFound)?;

I don't see an equivalent of this for web3.js, v1.95.
What's the idiomatic technique here?

What I've been trying is checking for null:
const interestBearingMintConfig = await getInterestBearingMintConfigState(mintAccount);
Kind of a hack though, because it's not definitive of extension absence. It could be a failed operation for other unknown reasons.

FWIW, I'm following this flow.

Solution found here:
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/14838/how-to-deserialize-all-the-extension-data-for-mint-account
